# Restoring rabbitmq-server database to a different host

Tags: rabbitmq, centos7

Im running rabbitmq-server-3.6.6-1.el7.noarch on a CentOS 7.4.1708 server.
The /var/lib/ directory, on an ext4 lvm partition, had insufficient storage issues which required us to extend the lvm online, in order to make more space.

This seemed to fix the problems at the time, but a rabbitmq-server service restart was needed, which, when attempted, hung.
The service never started up anymore. 
In order to get rabbitmq working again, the old mnesia directory was backed up, and a new one was created.

In order to recover the messages in the broken service, I have moved the old mnesia to a new server, added `NODENAME=rabbit@oldserver` to `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` on the new server and tried to start it, but it keeps failing to start.

Please how can I start the old rabbitmq database on the new host?

```
    [root@newserver]# cat /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf 
    NODENAME=rabbit@oldserver
```

When I try to start the service on the new server:

```
    [root@newserver rabbitmq]# systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service -l
    ? rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-05-07 16:25:23 WAT; 1h 32min ago
      Process: 6484 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 5997 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Main PID: 5997 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
       Status: "Exited."

    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local rabbitmqctl[6484]: * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local rabbitmqctl[6484]: other nodes on oldserver: ['rabbitmq-cli-20']
    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local rabbitmqctl[6484]: * suggestion: start the node
    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local rabbitmqctl[6484]: current node details:
    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local rabbitmqctl[6484]: - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-20@newserver'
    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local rabbitmqctl[6484]: - home dir: .
    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local rabbitmqctl[6484]: - cookie hash: edMXQlaNlKXH72ZvAXFhbw==
    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
    May 07 16:25:23 newserver.dom.local systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service failed.


    =ERROR REPORT==== 7-May-2018::16:16:43 ===
    ** Generic server <0.145.0> terminating
    ** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',
                               {submit_async,
                                   #Fun<rabbit_queue_index.32.103862237>}}
    ** When Server state == undefined
    ** Reason for termination == 
    ** {function_clause,
           [{rabbit_queue_index,parse_segment_entries,
                [<<1,23,0,255,54,241,95,251,201,20,69,202,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                   240,0,0,1,176,131,104,6,100,0,13,98,97,115,105,99,95,109,101,
                   115,115,97,103,101,104,4,100,0,8,114,101,115,111,117,114,99,101,
                   109,0,0,0,8,47,98,105,108,108,105,110,103,100,0,8,101,120,99,
                   104,97,110,103,101,109,0,0,0,7,98,105,108,108,105,110,103,108,0,
                   0,0,1,109,0,0,0,13,98,105,108,108,105,110,103,95,113,117,101,
                   117,101,106,104,6,100,0,7,99,111,110,116,101,110,116,97,60,100,
                   0,4,110,111,110,101,109,0,0,0,7,48,0,0,0,0,0,2,100,0,25,114,97,
                   98,98,105,116,95,102,114,97,109,105,110,103,95,97,109,113,112,
                   95,48,95,57,95,49,108,0,0,0,1,109,0,0,0,240,123,34,115,104,111,
                   114,116,67,111,100,101,34,58,34,52,50,54,95,109,101,110,117,115,
                   34,44,34,116,105,109,101,115,116,97,109,112,34,58,34,50,48,49,
                   56,45,48,52,45,49,56,84,49,48,58,53,57,58,50,55,46,57,51,53,90,
                   34,44,34,109,115,105,115,100,110,34,58,34,50,51,52,57,48,57,51,
                   52,52,57,50,57,51,34,44,34,105,100,34,58,34,50,55,50,49,56,95,
                   50,51,52,57,48,57,51,52,52,57,50,57,51,95,49,53,50,52,48,52,57,
                   48,52>>,
            ------snip-------goes-on-forever----

                                  100,0,4,116,114,117,101>>},
                            no_del,no_ack},
                           undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                           undefined,undefined,undefined},
                          10,10,10,10},
                         100,100,100,100,100},
                        1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000},
                       10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000}},
                  8988}],
                [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1067}]},
            {rabbit_queue_index,'-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,863}]},
            {lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1224}]},
            {rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,989}]},
            {rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,856}]},
            {rabbit_queue_index,scan_segments,3,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,676}]},
            {rabbit_queue_index,queue_index_walker_reader,2,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,664}]},
            {rabbit_queue_index,'-queue_index_walker/1-fun-0-',2,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,645}]}]}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? What do the logs say? Have you checked all the paths referenced in the docs [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html) and [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/backup.html) to start, make sure you didn't miss key data?

Comment: Hi @Olivier, yes I have checked the docs you posted, and I have added the logs and epmd stacktrace where the error happens.